# Links not working menu items in bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new to web development and the bootstrap framework. What I simply want is that when I click on one of the options in the bootstrap navbar (specifically the team option) it should take me to that specific page. This is the only link I have in my menu that takes me to a different pages. All other links take to specific sections on the same page. 
[image]

When I open up the Console Window, I get the following error message - https://gyazo.com/001f90dc8207f99c8692946df9f49163

Here is the HTML Code :

```
<nav class="navbar" data-spy="affix">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="images/logo-navy.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" target="_blank">Home<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#partners">Partners</a><li>
                            <li><a href="#news">In the news</a><li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!--<li><a href="/resources.php" target="_blank">Resources</a><li>-->
                        <li><a href="/team.php" data-target="/team.php" target="_blank">Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line with this and check

```
<li><a href="team.php" data-target="team.php" target="_blank">Team</a></li>
```

Comment: 1-Do you have this page on your server- team.php ?
2- Which links opens when you click on this link or what exactly happens ?

Comment: Yes I have team.php in the same folder as index.php. Nothing happens when I click on the button. I get that jQuery error in the console, when I click on the button.

Comment: Weird ! can you try this without data-target 
<li><a href="team.php" target="_blank">Team</a></li>
 Also check a simple link somewhere on your page - <a href="team.php">team</a>

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
data-target="/team.php"
```

from the link. data-target, I believe, is Bootstrap using JQuery to look for an item on the page. So JQuery is being called, but it isn't able to find /team.php.